I do not receive Push Notifications on iOS with .NET MAUI and Shiny. Works for Android
I am developing an App in .NET MAUI 8 for iOS 13+ and Android Target 27+. The App is done except for the support for receiving and handling Push Notifications. I decided to use Shiny.Push for this because I am already using Shiny successfully for other parts of my App.
It works perfectly fine for Android, but I do not get notifications for iOS.
Apple
I created a new App in Apple's App Store Connect and used its Bundle ID and Name when configuring CFBundleIdentifier and CFBundleDisplayName in my App's Info.plist.
I added an Identifier in Apple's Apple Developer site for the new App and I checked the option "Push Notifications" (as well as the other ones I need). I created two certificates for Push Notifications for this Identifier: one for Sandbox and one for Production. I can see them under "Certificates". I converted them into .p12 files and use these in our Push API that we use to send Push Notifications to Android and iOS devices.
Configuration
For iOS, I added the following code to my Entitlements.plist:
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>development</string>

I also added the following to my Info.plist:
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>

Startup
When the application starts, I declare using Shiny.
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
               ...
               .UseShiny()

Later, I declare the services I intend to use.
        builder.Services.AddShinyService<DefaultPushDelegate>();
#if IOS
        builder.Services.AddShinyService<PushManager>();
        builder.Services.AddPush();
#elif ANDROID
        builder.Services.AddPush(new FirebaseConfig());
#endif

I confirmed via breakpoints that my code inside the #if IOS block is reached when running the code on an iPhone.
AppDelegate
I made my AppDelegate class implement the interface IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate. I successfully receive the call of RegisteredForRemoteNotifications when the application starts and I store the Device Token in my session. I do NOT get any other events unfortunately.
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        var result = base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);

        var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;

        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
        {
            if (granted && error == null)
            {
                this.InvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                    // some more stuff
                });
            }
        });

        return result;
    }

    [Export("application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:")]
    public void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{this}.RegisteredForRemoteNotifications > BRO > {nameof(application)} = [{application}], {nameof(deviceToken)} = [{deviceToken}]");

        var sessionModel = IPlatformApplication.Current?.Services.GetService<SessionModel>();
        if (sessionModel != null)
        {
            sessionModel.DeviceToken = Convert.ToHexString(deviceToken.ToArray()).ToLower();
        }

        global::Shiny.Hosting.Host.Lifecycle.OnRegisteredForRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
    }

    [Export("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:")]
    public void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{this}.FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications > BRO > {nameof(application)} = [{application}], {nameof(error)} = [{error}]");

        global::Shiny.Hosting.Host.Lifecycle.OnFailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(error);
    }

    [Export("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{this}.DidReceiveRemoteNotification > BRO > {nameof(application)} = [{application}], {nameof(userInfo)} = [{userInfo}]");

        global::Shiny.Hosting.Host.Lifecycle.OnDidReceiveRemoteNotification(userInfo, completionHandler);
    }
}

Implementation of the Push Delegate
I am using the most simple implementation of the Shiny Push Delegate interface.
public class DefaultPushDelegate : IPushDelegate
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task OnEntry(PushNotification notification)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{this}.OnEntry > BRO > {nameof(notification)} = [{notification}]");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public async Task OnReceived(PushNotification notification)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{this}.OnReceived > BRO > {nameof(notification)} = [{notification}]");

        // my handling of the notification
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{this}.OnNewToken > BRO > {nameof(token)} = \"{token}\"");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task OnUnRegistered(string token)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{this}.OnUnRegistered > BRO > {nameof(token)} = \"{token}\"");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

I do not get any calls on iOS. As mentioned before, on Android, everything works as expected.
Sending Push Notifications
We have an API that sends out Push Notifications to Android and/or iOS devices which is in production for several years and works great. What I have done is to extend it so that all notifications are not only sent to the currently used Apps, but also to my new one. This way, I can easily test the reception and handling of Push Notifications. When I send a Push Notification through the API, I receive it on our old Java Android App, my new .NET MAUI App on Android, the old Swift App on iOS, but NOT on my new .NET MAUI iOS App. In all four cases, I use real devices in front of me. The only difference in sending Push Notifications from the API between the two iOS Apps are the p12 certificates that are used to send. I try both the development and the production ones.
I must have missed something, but I do not see what it is. Any ideas?

Are you testing with hot reload?

Yes, I start the App directly from Visual Studio to see the log output in the console to know whether I received notifications or not.

With automatic provisioning?

What I am thinking about: Hot restart is great, but it comes with tons of limitations. It works to test "Hello world" application, but for anything else... lets just say I learned the hard way not to trust it. So if you have MAC gathering dust around, you can do more "real" test there.

I found that ShinyOrg recently created this PushTester end-to-end example of how to wire things up. Maybe that can be used to troubleshoot?
Side note: I can highly recommend looking at readme which lists requirements for the setup to work. From the readme: If you're on iOS & debugging, you will need to be pointed at a sandbox setup environment (which was the final piece I needed to change in order to receive notifications in debug mode).
